# Deploy react app to S3Bucket from bitbucket pipeline

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, bitbucket

I am trying to deploy React app to AWS S3 bucket from BitBucket. When i run the pipeline custom:staging, i got error. Here is my bitbucket-pipelines.yml file:

```
image: node:10.15.3

pipelines:
  custom: # Pipelines that can only be triggered manually
    staging:
      - step:
          name: Installing & Running Tests
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - rm -rf package-lock.json
            - rm -rf node_modules
            - npm install
            - npm run test
      - step:
          name: Build
          script:
            - npm install --production
            - REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT=staging npm run build
          artifacts:
            - build/**
      - step:
          name: Deploy to S3
          deployment: staging
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-s3-deploy:0.2.4
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                S3_BUCKET: $STAGING_BUCKET_NAME
                ACL: "public-read"
                LOCAL_PATH: "build"
      - step:
          name: Invalidate Cloudfront Cache
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-cloudfront-invalidate:0.1.1
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                DISTRIBUTION_ID: $STAGING_DISTRIBUTION_ID
    production:
      - step:
          name: Installing & Running Tests
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - rm -rf package-lock.json
            - rm -rf node_modules
            - npm install
            - npm run test
      - step:
          name: Build
          script:
            - npm install --production
            - REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT=production npm run build
          artifacts:
            - build/**
      - step:
          name: Deploy to S3
          deployment: production
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-s3-deploy:0.2.4
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                S3_BUCKET: $PRODUCTION_BUCKET_NAME
                ACL: "public-read"
                LOCAL_PATH: "build"
      - step:
          name: Invalidate Cloudfront Cache
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-cloudfront-invalidate:0.1.1
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                DISTRIBUTION_ID: $PRODUCTION_DISTRIBUTION_ID
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Installing & Running Tests
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - rm -rf package-lock.json
            - rm -rf node_modules
            - npm install
            - npm run test
```

I am keep getting this error.

The environment 'staging' in your bitbucket-pipelines.yml doesn’t match any environment defined in your settings. Either update your yml, or your settings, to use the same name.

I checked the indentation. Indentation seems correct.

Comment: You could use Bitbucket as source provider in AWS CodeBuild  and create your pipeline with AWS pipeline it's simpler than Bitbucket pipelines

Comment: Your pipeline expects 'staging' branch - is there a branch with exactly that name in you git repository?